# boost::this_thread::sleep_for sleeping entire program

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads, c++98

**C++98 and Boost 1.54**

I'm having trouble figuring out why using `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` is sleeping my entire program. The only time and place the `Wait()` function is called is inside this thread, and this thread's sole purpose is to read file names in a directory and trigger an upload.

But for some reason, when it reaches the `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` line in the `Wait()` function, it hangs there and sleeps all the other threads as well. I'm unsure what I am missing, so any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```c++
void Upload::ReadFileNames()
{
    cout << "[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> A " << endl;
    Wait();  
    cout << "[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> B " << endl;


    // read filename stuff
}

void Upload::Wait()
{
    typedef boost::chrono::duration<long, boost::ratio<60> > seconds;
    int randomWaitTime = 0;
    try{   
        randomWaitTime = lexical_cast<unsigned int>(getId());
        randomWaitTime = randomWaitTime * 10;
    }
    catch ( const boost::bad_lexical_cast & e){
        // cout << "[LOG] FileUpLoad : Wait : bad_lexical_cast : "  << e.what() << endl ;
        randomWaitTime = 0;
    }

    seconds testTimeToWait(randomWaitTime);

    cout << "[DEBUG] Wait() -> A" << endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(testTimeToWait);
    cout << "[DEBUG] Wait() -> B" << endl;

    cout << "RANDOM WAIT TIME = " << randomWaitTime << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```c++
int  main()
{   
    pthread_t threadA; 
    pthread_create(&threadA,NULL,threadAfn,NULL);

    pthread_t threadB;
    pthread_create(&threadB,NULL,threadBfn,NULL);

    pthread_t Upload;    //  <--- Thread in question
    pthread_create(&Upload,NULL,Uploadfn,NULL);

    pthread_join(threadA,NULL);
    pthread_join(threadB,NULL);
    pthread_join(Upload,NULL); // <--- Thread in question

    return 0; 
}
```

**Output**

```
[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> A 
[DEBUG] Wait() -> A
// hangs here and rest of the threads are locked/slept as well?
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sorry this is for boost 1.53 and C++98 (legacy code). Post updated.

Comment: It is still not clear what the interaction between the other threads are with the problematic thread. Try to post a [MCVE]. Use a debugger to find out where the other threads are blocked. Make sure the other threads are not actually already finished.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no problem. I'll do a little more digging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it hangs there and sleeps all the other threads as well

No it doesn't. If it **seems** that way, that is because the other threads were *already* stuck or finished.

Look for things that block (mutex.lock, condition wait, IO operations, etc.) or check that the threads didn't exit.

### Notes

1. Your `seconds` calculations is off. On my system, the following:

   **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/853fd301333f2a2f)**

   ```
   #include <boost/chrono.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       std::cout << boost::chrono::duration<long, boost::ratio<60> >(1)/boost::chrono::seconds(1) << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   60
   ```

   So, what you *named* `seconds` is actually minutes. Just do this instead:

   ```
   using boost::chrono::seconds;
   int delay = std::strtoul(getId().c_str(), NULL, 10)*10;
   sleep_for(seconds(delay));
   ```
2. Your random delay is only random if the `getId` return is. Using `boost/random.hpp` you can make it truly random, with good range control. E.g. to sleep between 1'000 and 3'000 ms:

   int random_gen(int low, int high) { // not threadsafe
       static boost::random_device rdev;
       static boost::mt19937 prng(rdev);
       return boost::uniform_int<>(low, high)(prng);
   }

   void Upload::Wait() {
       int const ms_delay = random_gen(1000, 3000);
       cout << "RANDOM WAIT TIME = " << ms_delay << endl;
       sleep_for(milliseconds(ms_delay));
   }

   > Note to seed using `random_device` as shown (so true random seed) you need to link the random library. Otherwise, you can "stoop" to a time-based seed:
   >
   > ```
   >  static boost::mt19937 prng(std::time(NULL));
   > ```

Here's a self-contained version of your code with the various suggestions applied, demonstrating that there is no deadlock/softlock:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/680bb4df57ce93f3)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

using boost::this_thread::sleep_for;
using boost::chrono::seconds;
using boost::chrono::milliseconds;

using boost::lexical_cast;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Upload {
    std::string getId() const { return "42"; }
    void Wait();
    void ReadFileNames();
};

void Upload::ReadFileNames() {
    cout << "[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> A " << endl;
    Wait();
    cout << "[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> B " << endl;

    // read filename stuff
}

int random_gen(int low, int high) { // not threadsafe
    static boost::mt19937 prng(std::time(NULL));
    return boost::uniform_int<>(low, high)(prng);
}

void Upload::Wait() {
    int const ms_delay = random_gen(1000, 3000);
    cout << "RANDOM WAIT TIME = " << ms_delay << endl;
    sleep_for(milliseconds(ms_delay));
}

void background(char const* name) {
    // desync different background threads
    sleep_for(milliseconds(boost::hash_value(name) % 1000));

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        sleep_for(seconds(1));
        std::clog << name << " " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

void threadAfn() { background("thread A"); }
void threadBfn() { background("thread B"); }

void Uploadfn() {
    Upload u;
    u.ReadFileNames();
}

int main() {
    boost::thread threadA(threadAfn);
    boost::thread threadB(threadBfn);
    boost::thread Upload(Uploadfn);

    threadA.join();
    threadB.join();
    Upload.join();
}
```

Prints, e.g.:

```
[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> A 
RANDOM WAIT TIME = 1150
[DEBUG] ReadFileNames -> B 
thread A 0
thread B 0
thread A 1
thread B 1
thread A 2
thread B 2
thread A 3
thread B 3
thread A 4
thread B 4
```

Comment: Took a timetravel to 2013 (boost 1.54) and 2015 (GCC 4.9.3) just to verify that it works there too https://wandbox.org/permlink/SDBIRpZUdep9q2ti